# Lookup fail while programming a tree in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am trying to program my first binary tree but when I was programming a method to return true if the given target is in the binary tree (recursive helper) I got an error. Here is the code:

```
public class IABinaryTrees {
    private Node root;

    private static class Node {
        Node left;
        Node right;
        int data;

        Node(int newData) {
            left = null;
            right = null;
            data = newData;
        }
    }

    public void Binarytree() {
        root = null;
    }

    public boolean lookup(int data) {
        return(lookup(root, data)); //The fail is in this line 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    } 
}
```

Comment: The lookup method only takes one argument (data), and you are using two (root and data). Maybe you want to call root.lookup(data)?

Comment: Please correct indentation, this can't even compile

Comment: Either that, or there is a two parameter version of `lookup`, and please post it here.

Comment: What's the error? And where is lookup(root,data) defined?

Comment: I think the best way to answer is: "What do you expect to happen? What method are you expecting to get called?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This currently does not compile. The error it gives on the line you mention is(this is what eclipse tells me, probably not the official java compile error):

```
The method lookup(int) in the type IABinaryTrees is not applicable for the arguments (IABinaryTrees.Node, int)
```

This is saying that you have a method lookup which accepts an `int`. But you do not have a method lookup which accepts a `Node` and an `int`.

Fixing the error is easy. Make a new method with the right signature, or remove root from the call.

This will obviously not make the code work, it looks like you have a long way to go still, but this is addressing the error that you were getting, which is the question.